# cannot add vehicles to array list

Tags: java

I have 4 classes.. TaxiCo, Vehicle, Taxi and Shuttle.
I made taxi and Shuttle to inherit from vehicle class.. so now instead of adding a shuttle bus and adding taxi I just want to be able to add vehicle.. but I get an error saying constructor vehicle in class vehicle cannot be applied to give types.. I dont know whats wrong, as all I did is modify the add taxi method which worked fine..

Taxi Co class

```
import java.util.*;
public class TaxiCo
{
    // The name of this company.
    private String companyName;
    // The name of the company's base.
    private final String base;    
    // The fleet of taxis.
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> VehicleFleet;
    // A value for allocating taxi ids.
    private int nextID;
    // A list of available destinations for shuttles.
    private ArrayList<String> destinations;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class TaxiCo.
     * @param name The name of this company.
     */
    public TaxiCo(String name)
    {
        companyName = name;
        base = "base";
        VehicleFleet = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        nextID = 1;
        destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
        fillDestinations();
    }

    /**
     * Record that we have a new Vehicle.
     * A unique ID will be allocated.
     */
     public void addVehicle()
    {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(base, "Vehicle #" + nextID);
        taxiFleet.add(vehicle);
        // Increment the ID for the next one.
        nextID++;
    }

    /**
     * Return the Vehicle with the given id.
     * @param id The id of the Vehicle to be returned.
     * @return The matching Vehicle, or null if no match is found.
     */
    public Vehicle lookup(String id)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        Vehicle Vehicle = null;
        Iterator<Vehicle> it = VehicleFleet.iterator();
        while(!found && it.hasNext()) {
            Vehicle = it.next();
            if(id.equals(Vehicle.getID())) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(found) {
            return Vehicle;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the status of the Vehicle fleet. 
     */
    public void showStatus()
    {
        System.out.println("Current status of the " + companyName + " fleet");
        for(Vehicle Vehicle : VehicleFleet) {
            System.out.println(Vehicle.getStatus());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Put all the possible shuttle destinations in a list.
     */
    private void fillDestinations()
    {
        destinations.add("Canterbury West");
        destinations.add("Canterbury East");
        destinations.add("The University");
        destinations.add("Whitstable");
        destinations.add("Herne Bay");
        destinations.add("Sainsbury's");
        destinations.add("Darwin");
        destinations.add("Keynes");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `main` method?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note the document is being reviewed and discussed on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831), contributions welcome. 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: 1 moment will add it at bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `addVehicle()` method from `TaxiCo` class, you are passing 2 `String`s to the constructor, while you defined it with just 1 `String` as parameter.

```
public void addVehicle()
{
    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(base, "Vehicle #" + nextID); // BAD! Calling with 2 Strings
    taxiFleet.add(vehicle);
    // Increment the ID for the next one.
    nextID++;
}
```

You must change it, so you pass as parameter just 1 `String`. Something like:

```
Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle("Just one STRING!");
```

**Edit:** You are also doing this with the `Taxi` constructor in the method `addTaxi`

Comment: I dont get what you mean.. if i pass just one string it still doesnt work

Comment: Are you getting another, or the same error? Please edit your post with the stack trace.

Comment: ah, dont worry :) i figured it our :) i have another question tho.. for getStatus in vehicle class.. i need want it to return a message if the taxi is free.. but i could manage it.. can you help me out with that?

Comment: Oh.. but if i dont pass the base and + nextID string.. all i get are nulls in my array list :/

Comment: All these questions, looks like a design problem, just think on parameters that each method needs, and do the aproppriate changes to your code.